# child container still go outside of parent 100vh

Tags: html, css

This is sort of a two in problem.

I have a body with `height: 100vh` similar to how my example is in the jsFiddle (except in there I put 20vh.

I have a similar structure as this, where the innerRight container can be quite large compared to the rest of the content, and only that conatiner is to obtain it's own scroll bar. I sort of got this working in my main project, but the outer container (similar to how I displayed outer in the example) still expands past the the parents height container `main`. Be it 100vh, or 20vh it doesn't matter it doesn't stay within with `display:flex`.

```css
.main {
  height: 20vh;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.innerLeft {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

.innerRight {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">
    some random text
  </div>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="innerLeft">
    </div>
    <div class="innerRight">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but there is no 100vh in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you.

1. You have to set `height:100vh;` in `.main`  and set `width:calc(100% - 50px)`; to `.innerRight`.
2. Remove height from `innerleft` and `innerright` element.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/9Lsyzg64/1/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  height: 100vh;

}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 19px);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.innerLeft {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.innerRight {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: red;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">
    some random text
  </div>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="innerLeft">
    </div>
    <div class="innerRight">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set height to outer class.

```css
.main {
  height: 20vh;

}
.outer {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  overflow:hidden;
  
}

.innerLeft {
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

.innerRight {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">
  some random text
  </div>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="innerLeft">
    </div>
    <div class="innerRight">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```